# Folders stored on USB drive suddenly changed into unix executable file

Tags: macos, usb, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery, files-folders

I am a user of MacOS Big Sur, 11.2.3 (20D91). Just now I experienced the most weird incident in my history of using USB flash drives.

I mounted a drive on the MacOS system, hoping to transfer four directories stored on the drive into the computer. Each directory contained about 3.0 GB of files, and all directories looked normal when the drive was mounted. I opened and checked each directory, and everything was quite good.

The first directory was transferred in its entirety without causing any issue. But when the second directory was transferred, the 'Folder' app sent a notification to the desktop saying that the USB drive had been ejected incorrectly. I felt confused, since I did not pull out the drive or force it to be ejected.

I then pulled out the drive before mounting it back to the computer. The first and second directories were still intact, but the third and fourth directories became Unix Executable Files. I could not open them at all in the 'Folder' app.

How can I restore the corrupted directories to their original state? I'm afraid unless I restore them, I will forever lose the data contained in them.

There are two pictures I hope make the situation clear.

[image: USB Drive Information copied from Disk Utilities]

[image: What the drive looks like now]

Comment: How big did the drive say it was? The 16GB in the first pic? Have you ever successfully filled it to capacity & copied the data off again? In other words, have you ever actually tested its full capacity, either manually or using a test tool? My prime suspicion would be that the advertised capacity was not the real capacity & it suffered a hard crash when it tried to access 'non-real' space.

Comment: Hi Tetsujin, thanks for your comment. I was aware of the 16GB capacity advertised. I did successfully copy all four directories into it yesterday. From my calculations they added up to less than the full capacity. I don't have any doubt about its real capacity as a result.

Comment: Copying the data **in** isn't the test. Copying it back **out** is the test. So, in other words this was its maiden flight, & my initial suspicion still stands. There used to be a couple of apps on Mac that would test capacity, but they seem to have gone. The only way I know is to fill it to capacity & then copy out again, manually. See https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10112/software-to-verify-the-integrity-of-a-flash-sd-card

Comment: Sure, thanks for posting the link. I'll test the capacity on my own to find out more about this figure on the USB drive.

Comment: Have you worked out this problem?